# Avoid repeating a superclass' package name in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, package

How can I avoid repeating a long tedious package name in matlab classes in the following cases:

- When specifying the Superclass, e.g. `classdef Class < tediouspkgname.Superclass`
- When calling the superclass constructor, e.g. `obj = obj@tediouspkgname.Superclass(...)`.
- When calling superclass methods, e.g. `val = somefunc@tediouspkgname.Superclas(...)`.

I'm looking for an equivalent of matlabs `import` statement, which is not usable in these cases unfortunately.

---

### MWE:

Lets have a folder called `+tediouspkgname/` in our Matlab path. So Matlab recognizes there's a package called `tediouspkgname`.

Lets have a Class `ExampleClass` which is saved in the file `+tediouspkgname/ExampleClass.m`:

```
classdef ExampleClass
    properties
        p
    end
    methods
        function obj = ExampleClass(p)
            obj.p = p;
        end
        function print(obj)
            fprintf('p=%s\n',obj.p);
        end
    end
end
```

Let there be another Class, derived from ExampleClass, living in the file
`+tediouspkgname/DerivedClass.m`:

```
classdef DerivedClass < tediouspkgname.ExampleClass
    methods
        function obj = DerivedClass(p)
            obj = obj@tediouspkgname.ExampleClass(p);
        end
        function print(obj)
            print@tediouspkgname.ExampleClass(obj);
            fprintf('--Derived.\n');
        end
    end
end
```

I want the following commands to work without errors while mentioning `tediouspkgname.` as little as possible:

```
e = tediouspkgname.ExampleClass('Hello');
e.print();

o = tediouspkgname.DerivedClass('World');
o.print();
```

In particular, this definition of `DerivedClass` gives me the error `ExampleClass is not a valid base class`:

```
classdef DerivedClass < tediouspkgname.ExampleClass
    methods
        function obj = DerivedClass(p)
            obj = obj@tediouspkgname.ExampleClass(p);
        end
        function print(obj)
            import tediouspkgname.ExampleClass
            print@ExampleClass(obj);
            fprintf('--Derived.\n');
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You must specify the fully qualified name which includes the package name. The solution is to not make your package name be as long as tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two examples at the command line:

```
e = tediouspkgname.ExampleClass('Hello');
e.print();

o = tediouspkgname.DerivedClass('World');
o.print();
```

For these cases, you can use `import` at the command line:

```
import tediouspkgname.*
e = ExampleClass('Hello');
e.print();

o = DerivedClass('World');
o.print();
```

and it should work fine.

For the other cases you have (in the class definition line, and when calling a superclass method), you need to use the fully qualified name including the package.

I dislike this aspect of the MATLAB OO system. It's not just that it's tedious to write out the fully qualified name; it means that if you change the name of your package, or move a class from one package to another, you have to manually go through your whole codebase in order to find-and-replace one package name for another.